# Connect local IIS server to internet

Tags: windows-10, networking, iis

I want to connect my local IIS server to internet so I can access it from anywhere.

I have the following ISP restrictions:

- My router does not support **port forwarding**.
- My router is using **NAT** and **DHCP**.

Comment: Please read [Alternatives to Port Forwarding & NAT](https://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm): "There are four major problems that you may run into that would require alternatives to port forwarding. " ...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "access it"? Do you access a IIS service (e.g. hosting a website), do you want to access the IIS configuration (e.g. through host system) or s.th. else?

Comment: I want  the access the website that is hosted on IIS.

Comment: Questions: (1) What model is the router? (2) Do you own it or does it belong to your ISP? (3) Is the router UPNP capable? (4) Does it support DMZ? (5) Are you on Windows 10?

Comment: Do you have a public IP address? Do you have a separate modem? If not does the router support PPPoE pass through?

Comment: @harrymc 

1. Its provided by my ISP.
2. I have it.
3.NO
4. this feature is available but it is disabled and no option to turn it on
5. Yes.

Comment: @Albin I don't have the public IP.

Comment: @Sunny Just to make sure: How did you verify that your router does not get assigned a public IP address?

Comment: if you an ip address this might help you:
https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/2886/How-to-configure-IIS-to-access-website-using-IP-address.html#:~:text=Go%20to%20Start%20%E2%86%92%20Administrative,to%20add%20a%20new%20binding.

Comment: @Sunny If you don't mind, I would appreciate some feedback to my answer before the bounty expires. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: Assuming from your last comment that you're behind a [carrier-grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT) you can ignore options 2 and 3. I'll just leave them in case they are helpful to other users.

There are several options, depending mainly on your IP type, your modem/router setup or in more general terms how your ISP implemented your internet connection (e.g. if a PPP connection is established or if it's some kind of "unusual" setup). I assume you want to connect other devices to the internet as well, not only the machine the IIS server runs on.

With the current info, the amount of detail that can be put in an answer is limited (the question is too broad) but in general, you should at least have the following options:

1. If you don't have a public IP address you will need to use a proxy or a VPN service (e.g. use AirVPN and setup a port forward, see [link](https://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm) in David's comment for further details). There is no way around that for "direct access" over the internet. If you don't need "direct access" you could login into a local machine on your network via a remote tool (e.g. Anydesk) and access your IIS from there.
2. If you have a public IP address and your router supports PPPoE pass through, you can establish a "software" internet connection directly through a device on your network (e.g. an HW-router that supports port forward, a "software router" you can install on an existing machine or directly on your server, just make sure to setup a firewall)
3. If the router does not support PPPoE but you do get a public IP, I recommend getting a different router/modem (depending on what hardware you have right now), that either supports port forwarding or PPPoE pass-through). Alternatively you could go with a service as shown in the first option.

Note: Most consumer / small business connections types (which I assume you use) I came about (e.g. DSL) have usually a straightforward setup of the PPPoE. Other connection types might require different/additional setups.