# Unable to access my local web server via WAN-IP (provided by ISP)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding

I was trying to build a small experimental server

1. I have set up windows to use internal static IP 192.168.1.10
2. I have forwarded the port number from my router to redirect all requests on port 80 to my PC

[image]

When I try to access `192.168.1.10` the web server replies to the request but it no replies when I try to access it through the WAN-IP
NB : I've disabled the firewall for both my PC & Router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You router's WAN IP is `10.128.40.X`. Unfortunately `10.0.0.0/8` ("10.xxx.xxx.xxx") is a [private IP range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) and therefore your IP belongs to your ISPs carrier-grade NAT (CGN) - it's **not** a public IP.

You can check this yourself by testing if your router's WAN IP matches your public IP. To do this you can use a website e.g. [whatsmyip.com](https://whatsmyip.com) to find your public IP address. If they don't match you are behind a carrier-grade NAT. If so, you might be able to access your server via IPv6, that is assuming you get one assigned by your ISP and your router supports it.

If IPv6 does not work and you still want a public IP, several workarounds exist. Easiest would be to ask your ISP to provide you with a public IP. Or you can use a VPN service or proxy that provides you with a public IP (or use a remote tool):

> If you don't have a public IP address you will need to use a proxy or
> a VPN service (e.g. use AirVPN and setup a port forward). There is no way around that for
> "direct access" over the internet if you are on CGN. If you don't need "direct access"
> you could login into a local machine on your network via a remote tool
> (e.g. Anydesk) and access your Server from there.

[see source for further details](https://superuser.com/questions/1588221/connect-local-iis-server-to-internet/1589343#1589343)

Comment: thank you for your reply what if I want that IP address (CGN ) to be accessible in that specific network

Comment: @User that depends on the ISP I would guess he blocks the access between the nodes. You have to either try or check with your ISP

Comment: is there a way that i can check without asking ISP ?

Comment: when I try to ping other routers using CGN IP the routers internet light blinks

Comment: Unless you have a second IP in the same range you have to check "blind" eg. using a ip/port scan. Just make sure you know what you are doing this might constitute an illegal action! You really should check with your ISP!

Comment: okay, I'll check that.  and also I tried to tracert the IP address (CGN) from the other device in the same  CGN network the request is forwarded up to the gateway of my CGN IP address . but after that, I get a request time out message