# Reach ports inside a LAN behind a 4G connection from outside

Tags: vpn, port-forwarding, ip-camera, network-camera, zoneminder

I have a remote site with cameras streaming with rtmp protocol which I want to reach from my home.

Locally, streams work fine and can be seen (BTW I'm using ZoneMinder).

In this site I have a 4G router with a SIM which works fine for navigating.

**The problem:** Mobile Carrier is not offering an actual public IP and my 4G router IP is inside their private network, then translated to a public shared IP (CGNAT). There's no chance that the carrier will bring me out from this CGNAT scheme. Consequently, redirecting my local ports on 4G router won't make them visible from the internet.

**I'm trying to understand if a VPN is the solution.**

I understand that I could make some implementation that would let my devices in remote site get into the home LAN securely if I had a VPN server at home.

But I don't get to see if there's a way to reach the ports behind the 4G router in remote site from home. Not sure if my lack of control about the Carrier translations makes impossible to use the 4G side as a server.

I'm trying to understand if those two softwares can make it:

- [SoftEtherVPN](https://www.softether.org/#What_is_SoftEther_VPN)
- [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/site-to-site-routing-explained-in-detail/)

but not sure for my particular case.

Comment: I have done this (needed for my work). Hardware VPN Router with IPSec VPN. 4G wireless card with upcharge (money) to get VPN passthrough on the 4G wireless card.  Works fine. Entry level commercial solution.

Comment: Sorry @John I can't understand what you depict. Not sure where you put the router or how your case of 4G card can be compared to a 4G router.

Comment: What I was saying is that the local site has a hardware VPN router and the remote site (for me) uses a 4G wireless card with an ISP NAT connection requiring the VPN passthrough capability.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VPN that supports port forward. But an easier alternative might be to access your streaming server via IPv6 - assuming you get one assigned by your ISP and your router supports it.

If IPv6 does not work, there are two work arounds (not just VPN):

> If you need "direct access" to your server via an IP you will need to use a proxy or a VPN service (e.g. use AirVPN and setup a port forward).

> If you don't need "direct access" you could login into a local machine on your network via a remote tool (e.g. Anydesk) and access your Server from there.

[see source for further details](https://superuser.com/questions/1588221/connect-local-iis-server-to-internet/1589343#1589343)

Comment: I can't get an IPv6 from my ISP, that bad prevision from ISPs is the root cause why the implemented CGNAT. Also I want the image recorder machine to be working outside the LAN behind the 4G remote LAN. Thus, I'll be checking the first option. Thanks.

Comment: Seems that AirVPN is not the perfect solution for my situation. It needs a machine in which it should be running the client to address the ports of this same machine. In my case I have an ip-cam and a router.

Comment: Yes of course, every solution will have that short coming unless you have s.th. you can install (or activate) on your router or your IPcam directly. You will need some kind of client within your LAN that connects to a server on the internet otherwise there is no way to reach you behind a carrier grade NAT.

Comment: If your devices don't have such capabilities, a cheap alternative would be for example to run a Rasberry Pi which can stay on and run the client software.